L'adjectif « partiaire » est-il superflu lorsqu'on parle d'un « colon partiaire » ?
Le Centre National de Ressources Textuelles et Lexicales définit le mot « colon » comme suit : « Exploitant d'une terre qui lui a été concédée par le propriétaire avec qui il doit partager les fruits de l'exploitation. »
Il y est aussi défini le mot « partiaire » comme suit : « Colon, fermier partiaire. Fermier qui partage avec le propriétaire les récoltes, le cheptel et les produits fermiers. »
Les deux définitions me semblent assez près l'une de l'autre, donc je me demande si elles sont en fait synonymes et si l'adjectif « partiaire » dans « colon partiaire » est superflu ?

Colon a un sens beaucoup plus étendu que celui décrit dans la question. On l'emploie surtout aujourd'hui pour nommer l'habitant d'une colonie qui en exploite les ressources au sens large, pas seulement agricoles, et qui a pu aussi s'approprier des terres, donc sans partage avec un propriétaire.
Partiaire est un terme juridique rare. On peut comprendre que l'expression colon partiaire et ses dérivés comme colonat partiaire, colonage partiaire, colonie partiaire aient été utilisés car colon seul correspondait originellement à une personne qui cultive une terre à laquelle il était attaché héréditairement alors que partiaire indique qu'un contrat lie la personne temporairement avec le propriétaire des terres.
De nos jours, pour nommer ce type de cultivateur, on entend plutôt parler de métayer (étymologiquement, qui partage sa récolte en deux moitiés) alors que le fermier, dans son sens restreint, paye un loyer fixe au propriétaire, le fermage, indépendant de sa récolte. Quand le propriétaire ne fait pas appel à un tiers pour tirer profit de ses terres, on peut l'appeler propriétaire exploitant.
